# Laravel App\Mail - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, exception

I'm facing a problem with `App\Mail::.`

```
Mail::to(['...@gmail.com'])->send(new NewOrdersRegistered('', ''));
```

How the hell this gives an Error Exception > Invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

I also tried:

```
Mail::to('...@gmail.com')->send(new NewOrdersRegistered('', ''));
```

The Laravel code that gives exception is:

```
protected function buildRecipients($message){
    foreach (['to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'replyTo'] as $type) {
        foreach ($this->{$type} as $recipient) {
            $message->{$type}($recipient['address'], $recipient['name']);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

But got the same error! I have the same code in another project that runs like a charm.

Thanks for any help given.

Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Lamimail;
use App\LamimailOrders;
use App\LamimailLines;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\NewOrdersRegistered;
use PDO;
use DB;
use Auth;


class LamimailController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // calls the middleware: SetDatabaseConnection
        $this->middleware('SetDatabaseConnection:lamimail');
    }

    /**
     * Obtem todas as encomendas (+linhas) em aberto no AS400 e insere na db caso não existam
     */
    public function cronjob1_execute ()
    {
        // Obtem os Utilizadores do Grupo Expedição
        $utilizadores_expedic = DB::connection('lamiapps')->table('tbl_users')->select('email')->where('group_id', '=', 3)->get();

        //dd($utilizadores_expedic);

        //dd($utilizadores_expedic[0]->name);
        Mail::to($utilizadores_expedic->email)->send(new NewOrdersRegistered('', ''));

        dd('end');

    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('lamimail.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: check your error's stack trace, on which file and line are you getting this error?

Comment: Hi @Hafez, I edited the post to include the answer to your question.

Comment: It's likely that one of `$this->to`, `$this->cc`, `$this->bcc` or `$this->replyTo` is not an array or Collection (might be `null` or something else), so it's invalid as the first argument of `foreach()`. Do some debugging, add a `dd($this->to, $this->cc, $this->bcc, $this->replyTo);` and see what each contains.

Comment: Hi @Tim, I get it but I'm passing the email to Mail::to(). I have done an dd($this->to) in App\Mail\NewOrdersRegistered and yes, its empty []. Didn't really know why :\

Comment: An empty array `[]` is fine in a `foreach()`, i.e. `foreach([] as $record)` won't do anything. `null` on the otherhand is not good; that causes an error.

Comment: @TimLewis, dd($this->to) is returning [ ] ... That the first time this happens to me, and it's very strange!

Comment: That's just `$this->to`... There's 4 variables you're checking, since you're looping; **what does `$this->cc`, `$this->bcc` and `$this->replyTo` contain?** Also, I have no idea how you're defining those variables; you haven't posted enough code for us to help with debugging...

Comment: @TimLewis I'm not checking anything, this is the framework job. The variables that I'm passing is the ones I posted. Thanks

Comment: I'm telling you to check them... That is debugging; one of those variables is not working in your `foreach()` loop, it's your job to determine which one and fix it. The framework is doing it's job by reporting the error to you, but it can't fix it; that's **your** job.

Comment: @TimLewis, I'm doing waht the Laravel Docs said to do when we want to send an email. Like I said, I use the same code in another project. I posted this here to try to get help. I know that the framework is doing the job right. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And I'm trying to help you help yourself by instructing you in good debugging practices... But whatever; hope you're able to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing an email to the function, you are attempting to pass the property of a collection (`email`) that does not exist. This is failing (and probably giving errors in your log) so the function gets sent `null` as a parameter.

```
    $utilizadores_expedic = DB::connection('lamiapps')
        ->table('tbl_users')
        ->select('email')
        ->where('group_id', '=', 3)
        ->get();
    // $utilizadores_expedic is now a collection of stdClass objects
    // but you are trying to get its email property which does not exist
    Mail::to($utilizadores_expedic->email)
        ->send(new NewOrdersRegistered('', ''));
```

According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#sending-mail),

> The `to` method accepts an email address, a user instance, or a collection of users. If you pass an object or collection of objects, the mailer will automatically use their `email` and `name` properties when setting the email recipients, so make sure these attributes are available on your objects.

Here is probably what you want:

```
    $utilizadores_expedic = DB::connection('lamiapps')
        ->table('tbl_users')
        ->select(['email', 'name'])
        ->where('group_id', '=', 3)
        ->get();
    Mail::to($utilizadores_expedic)
        ->send(new NewOrdersRegistered('', ''));
```

Though I am always concerned when I see anyone using the `DB` facade. It usually means models are not configured properly. It would be more like the Laravel way to have this:

```
    $utilizadores_expedic = Group::find(3)->users;
    Mail::to($utilizadores_expedic)
        ->send(new NewOrdersRegistered('', ''));
```

Comment: Hi @miken, thanks for your help! The problem is, >even< if I hard type the email like Mail::to('...gmail.com')->send(), it doesn't work too. So in this case, the problem isn't related to the query/model. Btw, I haven't used Groups model because of a different DB connection.

Comment: Well I can only critique the code you give us, and that code is wrong as I explain in my answer.

Comment: Regarding models with different connections, you can define your model and relationships with this information. For example, in `Groups` model define `protected $connection = 'lamiapps';` and in `Users` model define `protected $connection = 'otherconnection';` and it should work automatically.

Comment: Hi @miken, thanks! I know that. I hard typed to debug everything. The connections name comes from Auth::user()->database. The returned name are binded to a middleware to set connection.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally found the problem.**

We can't have `protected $replyTo;` defined in App\Mail\NewOrderRegistered, otherwise the framework will catch this variable.

I defined this because, I can have replyTo based on some cased.

I now realized that the correct approach is:

```
public function __construct($replyTo, $email_data)
{
    // If $replyTo has data, attach to email
    if (!empty($replyTo)) {
        $this->replyto($this->replyTo['email'], $this->replyTo['name']);
    }

    // set email data
    $this->email_data = $email_data;

    // set email subject
    $this->subject('...');
}
```

Thanks everyone that tried to help me.
Best Regards,
Helder